# Javascript error - NaN

Tags: javascript

i have been going at this code all afternoon and i cannot figure out why this error is occurring. here is the code:

```js
var ancestry = [{
  "name": "Carolus Haverbeke",
  "sex": "m",
  "born": 1832,
  "died": 1905,
  "father": "Carel Haverbeke",
  "mother": "Maria van Brussel"
}];

function average(array) {
  function plus(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }
  return array.reduce(plus) / array.length;
}

var byCentury = new Object();
for (var i = 0; i < ancestry.length; i++) {

  var centName = Math.ceil(ancestry[i].died / 100);
  if (centName in byCentury) {
    byCentury[centName].push(ancestry[i].age = ancestry[i].died - ancestry[i].born);
  } else {
    byCentury[centName] = [centName];
  }
}

for (var century in byCentury) {
  // For some reason no value is returned

  var ages = byCentury[century].map(function(person) {
    return person.age;
  });
  console.log(century + ': ' + average(ages));
}
```

The output i get is:

```
16: NaN
17: NaN
18: NaN
19: NaN
20: NaN
21: NaN
```

While the desired output is:

```
 16: 43.5
 17: 51.2
 18: 52.8
 19: 54.8
 20: 84.7
 21: 94
```

here is the challenge it has a built in code sandbox: http://eloquentjavascript.net/code/#5.3

Comment: What is the `average` function?

Comment: also sample of `ancestry` value

Comment: The `NaN` stands for "Not a Number". It means that somewhere you are using a variable that is a string, while it should be a number (probably in the `Math.ceil`). You can use `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` to convert a numeric string to an integer or float.

Comment: Try `parseFloat(ages)`

Comment: this is the average function function average(array) {
  function plus(a, b) { return a + b; }
  return array.reduce(plus) / array.length;
}

Comment: And here is a sample of ancestry '{"name": "Carolus Haverbeke", "sex": "m", "born": 1832, "died": 1905, "father": "Carel Haverbeke", "mother": "Maria van Brussel"}',

Comment: @maxlloyd Please update the `ancestry` in the question!

Comment: Specifically, please make a *complete* example that we can run and see the output ourselves. It'll help a lot with finding the problem.

Comment: ok i added the link to the challange it has a sandbox built in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
byCentury[centName].push(ancestry[i].age = ancestry[i].died - ancestry[i].born);
```

isn't pushing `ancestry[i]` into your array - it's pushing the value of `ancestry[i].age`. So later on, where you have:

```
var ages = byCentury[century].map(function(person) {
    return person.age;
});
```

`person` is actually a number, so `person.age` will be undefined.

The other problem you have at the moment is what happens when you come to a person in the `ancestry` array whose century of birth hasn't been stored in `byCentury` yet.

```
if (centName in byCentury) {
  ...
} else {
  byCentury[centName] = [centName];
}
```

Instead of storing their age, you store the number representing that century. One way of fixing it would be to change that block to:

```
if (byCentury[centName] === undefined) {
  byCentury[centName] = [];
}
byCentury[centName].push(ancestry[i].died - ancestry[i].born);
```

and simply logging `century + ': ' + average(byCentury[centName])` in your loop at the end. Finally, add in some rounding to make your output match that of the exercise, and you'll have your final solution.